# Getting error that actually not an error in vscode while using intelephense

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, intelephense

Getting unexpected error (Expected 1 arguments. Found 0) in vscode while using intelephense extension.
When I uninstall the intelephense extesion from vscode at that time this error not showing but i dont want to uninstall the extension.
how can i solve this issue??

[image]

Error starts showing when i write __construct method in (2.php) file.

[image]

Error:

[image]

Comment: You can try to downgrade intelephense to some earlier release

Comment: Try using namespaces

Comment: @Alex already tried with intelephense earlier versions but getting the same errors.

Comment: @brombeer your comment is the answer, namespaces resolve this issue, the problem is the class is trying to inherit through the IDE I believe, I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use namespaces as Brombeer suggests in the comment he made to your question, he deserves credit for this.

I define it based off of the class that the file contains, so I have a class named Animal, and keep the namespace within the Animal class:

```
<?php

namespace Animal;

class Animal ...
```

The error exists because the IDE thinks the class you're extending exists as it's using the global namespace

why it's in the global namespace:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php

namespaces:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php

edit: forgetting to add code blocks to comment...